# How to achieve multi line header in DataGridView using property grid?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to give the multi line header text in property grid for the DataGridView, I have used `\n`, `\r\n` but neither worked to get the header text in multiple lines. Is there a way other than setting the width of the column and leaving spaces to get this working using the property grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I used `Environment.NewLine` in the `designer.cs` where the header text was assigned. Though the property grid shows just a string with no newline characters, while the GridView renders, the header text was coming in multiple lines as expected.

Answer (score 6):

If possible use `Environment.NewLine` (which is \r\n in Windows), and set the Grid column `DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode` property to `DataGridViewTriState.True`.

```
dataGridView.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

Comment: Thanks, though I am trying to do this in the property grid itself.. I don't find any way of doing that..

Comment: You mean in the aspx?

Comment: No, on the designer, when you try to add/edit columns, a window that pops up has the ability to take the header text values for the columns.. thats where I was trying to set the header text with multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

The text ist taken literally, so in the Designer.cs File the HeaderText will be `"First_Line\\r\\nSecond_Line"`. Just replace `"\\"` by `"\"`  to `"First_Line\r\nSecond_Line"` and it works.